# Ck editor code not working when we edit the content in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

```
        <div class="form-group">
          <?php echo form_textarea(array('name' => 'txtdescription', 'id' => 'desc', 'class' => "ckeditor", 'value' => set_value('txtdescription', htmlspecialchars_decode($desc)))); ?>         
            </div>
```

This is my view code when we get data from db

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 3 argument for set_value.

Try this:

```
 <div class="form-group">
 <?php echo form_textarea(array('name' => 'txtdescription', 'id' => 'desc', 'class' => "ckeditor", 'value' => set_value('txtdescription', $desc,false))); ?>         
 </div>
```